# how to select all date exclude 30 days before today

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE INVOICE_DATE .....(30 days have passed since today).....
```

example:

today = 2021-11-05

2021-11-04 non select

2021-10-07 non select

2021-10-04 select

2021-09-27 select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, current date minus 30 days

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE INVOICE_DATE < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `time` library in python language.
Here's an example of how it can be done.

First of all, record the current date and time.

```py
import time
# This will store current datetime in epoch
epoch = time.time()
```

Then we import another library that will convert epoch to human-readable format.

```py
import datetime
# This will return a date and time of exactly 30 days before today
dateToSelect = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(epoch)-2592000)
```